# Running my OpenGL application over RDP displays nothing

Tags: opengl, rendering, rdp

I have an OpenGL application that has a map display window. When I run the application over RDP the map display is blank [blank-map-display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXjkg.png)

Running the same application locally or on AWS Workspaces the map displays correctly.

The machine I've RDP'd to has an NVidia graphics card and running windows 10. I've attempted to force hardware acceleration over RDP but this still doesn't solve the problem. Here is the DirectX Diagnostics details showing the use of HW rendering when I RDP on the machine: [dxdiag-rdp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhlaP.png). I'm using Nvidia driver version 451.77 which should support RDP for Nvidia GeForce GPUs.

I noted that on AWS Workspaces (and locally) all the DirectX features are enabled: [dxdiag-aws-workspaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yUjT.png).

Has anyone got any insight into how to make an OpenGL application run over RDP like it does on AWS Workspaces?

Comment: OpenGL is not DirectX, they are competing technologies. Microsoft is unlikely to ever support OpenGL over RDP. Even if they do, it will be unlikely that it will be accelerated by the AWS GFX card.

Comment: "Has anyone got any insight into why OpenGL doesn't seem to work over RDP?" That's an nvidia thing which they used to limit to quadro only. However, in the beginning of the current pandemic, they decided to allow it to be enabled for geforce cards, too: https://www.khronos.org/news/permalink/nvidia-provides-opengl-accelerated-remote-desktop-for-geforce-5e88fc2035e342.98417181

Comment: I tried what @derhass suggested but this didn't fix the problem.